# Anyone tried Youtube API iframe on IE9?

Tags: html, iframe, youtube-api

I'm trying to use the sample code on this page. I copy paste it into an html file and try to open it using IE9 and FF but nothing shows up. Any idea what I might be missing?

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/iframe_api_reference.html#Getting_Started

Comment: [Not working for me either](http://i.imgur.com/di0R7.png), I guess that's covered by the "experimental" status of this method.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that can help is making sure your page is rendered in standards mode by declaring it as `<!doctype html>`. However, that does not seem to fix all circumstances where the embed fails to load. (For example, it also doesn't like to load if the containing element isn't displayed.)

Answer (score 0):

Works for me only after deleting browser history.
So I'm guessing it may have something to do with resource de-allocation of some sort (although, I would expect the IE's Javascript interpreter to do it).

Comment: After further investigating this problem: Microsoft admits to have memory-leak issues when creating IFRAME elements (which is exactly what the YT.Player constructor does). Here it is on Microsoft website: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg622929%28v=VS.85%29.aspx?ppud=4.